# dojo validationTextBox invalid message or prompt message not appearing

Tags: dojo

I have been trying to show a invalid message from a validationTextBox some how its not working.
I copy pasted the examples from internet even then its not working.

i am using dojo 1.8 
below is my sample code

required attribute highlights the text box but the message is not shown
    enter code here
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    
    
    
    
    My Test

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="../MyTest2/js/dojoRoot/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <form id="addForm" dojoType="dijit.form.Form" action="save" method="post">
        <table>
        <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"
            value="someTestString" required="true" dataType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"                  promptMessage="please enter first name"                     invalidMessage="first name is empty" /></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Thanks 
Shasi

Answer (score 0):

you have used dataType attribute. It is "dojoType".
Now, "dojoType" has been replace with "data-dojo-type". you have mistaken it for dataType.
You can either use "dojoType" or "data-dojo-type"
Also, use missingMessage attribute to show the message whwn user moves out of field, without providing input. "required" is used along with "missingMessage"
promptMessage is used as a tool tip. It is displayed when user focuses on the field.
invalidMessage is used if any constraints mentioned is not satisfied when focus is moved away from the field. Let me give you a small example.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
    @import "./js/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./js/dojo/dojo.js' djConfig="parseOnLoad:true,isDebug:false">
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <input type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" id="namefld" name="namefld" required="true" missingMessage="Input is required for Name!" promptMessage="Pease enter you name!" regExp="[a-zA-Z]+" invalidMessage="Wrong input! Please correct!"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can any one help on this. im really stuck

Comment: what i infer is, your paths are wrong. Let me give you a clue.
inside the application folder ("application" folder in my case is inside the 'webapps' folder of tomcat), the html file is placed. Then, it has a folder called "js" for storing all the javascript stuff, which contains the dojo library.
webapps                                                         
|-application (in webapps folder of tomcatroot)
  |-index.html (in application folder)
  |-js  (inside application folder)
    |-dojo  (inside js folder)
    |-dijit (inside js)
    |-dojox (inside js)
    |-util (inside js)

Comment: please notice that, in my example, i used relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a different version (1.9) of Dojo, but if your problem is primarily cosmetic, here are two things to watch out for:

1. Some form elements will not show any red error markings until the user actually clicks on them or gives them focus with the keyboard. This makes sense in certain scenarios, like optional login forms in a sidebar. To avoid this, you can do `data-dojo-props="required:true, _hasBeenBlurred:true"` and the `_hasBeenBlurred` makes the widget assume the user has already interacted with it once before.
2. If you're trying to get "prompts" inside text-input fields (e.g. "Enter name...") it might not work on certain versions of IE, which do not support the [HTML5 `placeholder` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#attr-input-placeholder).